# Estimate of average grade

Tags: statistics

Say you have been tasked with estimating the average grade of students. All students in a province is your target population. It is known that the size of your target population is 80000. There are 26400 "A" students of these employees with those having an average grade of 95% per semester. Then you are able to collect information from a simple random sample of 100 of those students not on the "A" list. The mean grade in those sampled is 70% per semester, with a standard deviation of 5.

Give your estimate of the average grade amongst all students. Also give a 95% CI for the estimate.

Should I simply take the average of 95 and 70 to find the estimate? And for the 95 CI should I use 5/sqrt(100) * 1.96 ?

Comment: The estimation of the average grade is the weighted mean $0.95\cdot\frac{26,400}{80,000}+0.70\cdot\frac{80,000-26,400}{80,000}=0.7825$

Comment: how about the 95 CI for this estimate?

Comment: I´m still thinking. But first I´ll have a breakfast. I hope it helps.